# How to make a Texture fit more smoothley

Tags: texturing, uv

Im not sure if i should put this here or somwhere else.
Id like to make it look more smoother.
Any easy way to do this?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods :

1. Either you **Subdivide** your model & then unwrap it
2. Or if still the problem persists, then try UNWRAPPING in other way like 
   **PROJECT FROM VIEW** by selecting only those areas which create a problem & map your texture accordingly

This way you can get actual smooth look on the faces where such artifact is available